# How to calculate the fourier series coefficients of $(f(x))^m?$ knowing the Fourier series of $f$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

For sake of simplicity $f$ is assumed to be $2π-$periodic function on $\Bbb R$.  Given the fourier series of $f$, which coefficients  are

$$\widehat{f}(k)= \frac{1}{2π}\int_0^{2π}f(t)e^{-ikt}dt,~~~~~~k\in \Bbb Z. $$

how to calculate the fourier series coefficients of $(f(x))^m?$

> If I know the fourier series expansion of a function $f(x)$  is it possible to express the fourier series coefficients of $(f(x))^m$ as functions of fourier series coefficients of $f(x)?$
>
> Is there any general algorithm to calculate this?

I think by a recursive formula it suffices to find the result for $m=2$. Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: it could be great to explain your down vote it will help for sure. may be my question is too obvious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $$f(x)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \hat f(m)e^{imx}$$ then $$f(x)^2=\sum_{m,n=-\infty}^\infty\hat f(m)\hat f(n)e^{i(m+n)x}$$
  Letting $m=M-n$ gives $$\sum_{M,n=-\infty}^\infty\hat f(M-n)\hat f(n)e^{iMx}$$ so $$\widehat{f^2}(M)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat f(M-n)\hat f(n)=\hat f\ast \hat f,$$ where $\ast$ denotes the convolution of two sequences.  In general, $\widehat {f^m}=\hat f\ast \hat f\ast\cdots\ast \hat f$ $m$ times.